# SAML binding: Error getting X509Certificate2.PrivateKey on Azure

Tags: azure, certificate, private-key, x509certificate2, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

The ITFoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 library contains a function to bind the request that extracts private key from signing certificate.

```
 if(certificate is Saml2X509Certificate)
        {
            return (certificate as Saml2X509Certificate).GetRSAPrivateKey();
        }
        else
        {
            return certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
        }
```

It works on local machine but on azure, it is giving the following error.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean 
  randomKeyContainer)
  at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters 
 parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& 
 safeKeyHandle)
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters 
 parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
  at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.X509Certificate2Extensions.GetSamlRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
  at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding1.BindInternal(Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse)
  at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding.BindInternal(Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, String messageName)
  at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding1.Bind(Saml2Request saml2Request)
```

.

Not sure whether it is saml library issue or azure configuration issue since it works on local machine.
I am using the certificate provided in the test webapp example. So, it doesn't look corrupted.

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Azure App Service, maybe the problem is that you need to make the SSL/TLS certificates private key accessible for your web application.

Adding an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application.